# fitting a L shape (corner) to points to remove outliers

Tags: geometry, mathematical-modeling

I am trying to extract the length and width from a set lidar sensor points (pink) as shown in the image below. The points circled in blue and white are actually noise which I wish to eliminated. *[The orange box is the length and width I currently have calculated from the points. As seen, the calculated width is much 1/3 wider than it is supposed to be, due to the noisy points i blue and white]*

I've read some approaches to do corner/rectangle fitting, then discarding x% of the poorest fitting points. This would help me to get rid of the circled points. But so far, after many searches I still cannot find any concrete implementations on how to do this fitting.

Can any provide any suggestions how I can go about doing this? 
[image]

Comment: I find it difficult to understand your image. What is the blue shape? Can you show the actual box superimposed? Which side is the width? I don't see much noise near the top of the image, but a lot at the bottom. Where in the image are you trying to fit a corner?

Comment: @Jens, I have amended my question and edited the image to clarify things. the orange box's longer side is the length and shorter side is the width I have extracted right now. I'm trying to fit the L shape into the majority of the points so that points in the circles would have very high errors and hence be removed.